# jQuery FadeIn element one after another ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, delay, fadein, appendto

I have a problem, which according to other posts I read shouldn't be a problem.

What I am trying to do is grab content via ajax, iterate through the content and append it to the dom. Once the element is appended, fade it in, and then repeat. The problem which occurs, is all elements appear to fade in at once rather than one after another. I've tried tackling this a number of different ways. This is the closest to what I want however, the fadeIn , well doesn't transition, it just appears. Any help is greatly appreciated.

HTML

```
<ul id="search_results"></ul>
```

JS

```
function doSearch( jsonPath ){
$(function() {

    $.ajax({ url: jsonPath ,  dataType: 'json',
      async: false,

      success: function(data)  {


          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            if( data[key].name != "NA" ){
                setTimeout(function(){
                var html = ('<li class="searchResult" id="pic_' + key +'"><div class="searchProfileResult">' + 
                    '<div class="userimage"><img  title= "' +  data[key].title+'"src="' + data[key].picture +'" /></div></div></li>');
                    $(html).appendTo( $('#search_results') ).hide().fadeIn(2000);
                    }, (key*500) );

            }
          });
    }

    });
});
}
doSearch( jsonPath );
```

I've also tried

```
$.each( data, function( key, val ) {
        if( data[key].name != "NA" ){

            $('<li class="searchResult" id="pic_' + key +'"><div class="searchProfileResult">' + 
                '<div class="userimage"><img  title= "' +  data[key].title+'"src="' + data[key].picture +'" /></div></div></li>').appendTo( $('#search_results') ).hide().delay(key*500).fadeIn(2000);


        }
      });
```

I'm stumped so any help would be greatly appreciated. I

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `callback` feature in jQuery.

```
$('item').fadeIn(300,function(){

  //this is how you "chain" reactions
  $('item2').fadeIn(300);

})
```

This is really "cheating" to me, but it does the job I suppose.

```
var items, speed;

items = $('ul li')
speed = 300;
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  items.each(function(i, element) {
    $(element).delay(speed*i).fadeIn(speed);
  })

})
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4wBU/)**

Comment: How would you set it inside each loop?

Comment: I think you know darn well how :) set up a recursive animation function and use `each`'s built in `index,element` arguments, but that's a lot of code. Can't make it too easy now can I?

Comment: I was more thinking using a promise would be a better way but i need to think more about it on how to implement it regarding OP's code

Comment: I have tried that before, but no luck. I also read to add: the CSS {
 -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 } to my element, which does make it fade in, but then, the action is very eratic, like groups will fade in, as if it is trying to fade in the entire selector's group of elements instead of the item I am iterating on.

Comment: @Bren1818 yeah, css animations and javascript animations do not play nice together. general rule of thumb, if you're using js animations you don't need css - usually overrides or makes some nasty results. I know a quick and dirty method, I'll post some more code momentarily.

Comment: @Bren1818 added the code. Just know that if you want this to work with *many* items, it creates all of them at once and does not stop until they're all resolved. Will it still work? Depends on the client's resources. Just a word of caution, as the method in the 2nd comment is really the way to go - but I haven't got all day :)

Comment: 500 iterations and still going strong.. but it's also text and not something like images: http://jsfiddle.net/m4wBU/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should add all LIs in UL and make LIs hidden by default, then call internal method on first LI once done, using promise, e.g:

```
animateLI($('ul li:first'));

function animateLI($li) {
    $li.fadeIn(2000).promise().done(function () {
        if(!$(this).next().length) return;
        animateLI($(this).next());
    });
}
```

See a simplified DEMO to give you the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8v8E/1/

In your each loop, just set a string, append it to UL outside of each loop then call  animateLI() method on first LI.

Comment: I saw that response in another stack overflow posting. Problem with this answer is the elements just "appear" they do not fadeIn like they're supposed to. I'm totally stumped why they are not.

Comment: @Bren1818 an element to fadeIn() need to be hidden, i think you know it but who knows. You should provide a relevant jsFiddle which replicates your issue because you are doing something wrong i cannot be aware of

Comment: @A.Wolff You crashed my browser :( that's making JS go crazy with too many things at once in a loop.

Comment: @kcdwayne sorry, forgot to update jsfiddle with: `if(!$(this).next().length) return;`. Updated, should be better now ;)

Comment: I'll see if I can make a fiddle - problem is this is internal data which wouldn't be accessible outside. It seems like I can get the fade to work, but have no delay between each item, or display each item and have no fade.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally got it. Here's the final code:

```
function doSearch( jsonPath ){
$(function() {

    $.ajax({ url: jsonPath ,  dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      //data: myData,
      success: function(data)  {
          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            if( data[key].name != "NA" ){

                $('#search_results').append('<li class="searchResult" id="pic_' + key +'"><div class="searchProfileResult">' + 
            '<div class="userimage"><img  title= "' +  data[key].title+'"src="' + data[key].picture +'" /></div></div></li>');

            }
          });

    }}).done(function(){

        var items = $('#search_results li');
        var speed = 2300;
        $(document).ready(function(e) {

          items.each(function(i, element) {
            $(element).delay(100*i).fadeTo( "slow" , 1, function() {

            });
          })

        })


    });
});
```

}
doSearch( jsonPath );

It seemed I had to use fadeTo, and then the default CSS for the element should be:

```
<style>
#search_results li.searchResult{
    opacity: 0;
}
```